# « Ils ont été évacués » ou « ils ont évacué » ?

Tags: grammaire, passif

J'aimerais bien connaître la forme correcte utilisée par les francophones ?

> Ils ont été évacués.
>   Ils ont évacué la ville.

Laquelle est la forme passive ?
Est-ce que cette forme est utilisée par un francophone ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Évacuer" is a transitive verb. You'll hear both in French, but they have different meanings, mostly matching the English equivalents.

> Ils ont été évacué**s** -> They were evacuated.

i.e., they were carried out of the evacuation area by emergency services. Here the object (in a passive construction) is a person or persons.

> Ils ont évacué la ville. -> They evacuated the town.

Here "ils" usually refers to emergency services (i.e. "They had the town evacuated") but it could also refer to the population (i.e. "Everyone left town because of the evacuation"). Here the object is a place.

These corresponds to the meanings C and B of [the TLFi definition](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%A9vacuer). For completeness, I'll mention that meaning A refers to anything somewhat noxious that must be "expelled" from the mind or body.

Comment: Pourquoi répondre en anglais ? Sans être certain, je pense que l'OP préfère le français.

Comment: J'était dans l'impression que malgré la langue de la question, le niveau de français de l'OP laissait entendre qu'il était peut-être plus à l'aise en anglais.

Answer (score 1):

Cela dépend du contexte.

Un titre de journal marquerait plutôt: "Les habitants de la ville ont été évacués."

Ce qui marque totalement la forme passive demandé, une fois ceci fait *effectivement* la forme correcte est "Ils ont été évacués." pour commencer une phrase, mais ne sonne pas correctement toute seule, il manque un complément.

Comme: "Ils ont été évacués à 8 heures ce matin"
       "Ils ont été évacués dès la venue du président"

Là la phrase est parfaitement dans son contexte..

The sentence need to be refered to a subject (who is "ils"?) or need an object for mark the context to be correct.